# Vector operation on datasets

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have a dataset like:

```
set1 = {{-16.7057, -10.7875, -26.8102}, {-13.2357, 25.903, 13.9369},
        {22.6074,  3.4955, -30.795}, {8.31895, -15.6811, 42.3093}};
set2 = {{-16.705, -10.787, -26.81}, {-13.236, 25.903, 13.937},
        {22.607,  3.495, -30.795}, {8.319, -15.681, 42.309}}
```

They are pretty close to each other. Now I want to take the `Norm` of each element of `set1[[i]]` and subtract it from `Norm` of each element of the `set2[[i]]`. And get the output as `{a1, a2, a3, a4}`. How can I do that **without using** any loop like **For** loop?

---

I just want to add few things for the sake of completeness if the sets are like below then what should be the action:

```
set1b = {{{-16.7056, -10.78745,-26.81020}, {-13.235671, 25.903009, 13.936884}, {22.6074, 3.495498, -30.79496}, {8.3189, -15.681, 42.309}}, {{1.7960000, 34.50099, -10.9480`}, {-22.420000, -10.4510000, 24.980}, {1.183999,-42.707000000, -17.586999999}, {17.47500, 20.652000, 9.18399}}};

set2b = {{{-16.705`, -10.787`, -26.81`}, {-13.236`, 25.903`, 13.937`}, {22.607`, 3.495`, -30.795`}, {8.319`, -15.681`, 42.309`}}, {{1.796`, 34.501`, -10.948`}, {-22.42`, -10.451`, 24.981`}, {1.184`, -42.707`, -17.587`}, {17.475`, 20.652`,  9.184`}}};
```

Editted last part

Comment: It's very annoying when people wait for an answer to then change the rules of the question. **Please don't do that in the future**. Read about [moving the goalpost](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397)

Comment: I am sorry...never do it again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[normDif]
normDif = Apply[Subtract, Sqrt @ Total[{##}^2, {-1}], {0}] &;

normDif[set1, set2]
```

> {0.000672543, -0.000166313, 0.000281282, 0.00030175}

```
normDif[set1b, set2b]
```

> {{0.000606338, -0.000177899, 0.00024899, -0.0000181312},
>     {-9.51991*10^-6, -0.000710573, -2.60074*10^-8, -3.2146*10^-6}}

**Timings:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
{s1, s2} = RandomReal[1000, {2, 1000000, 3}];

r1 = normDif[s1, s2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0887

```
r2 = Norm /@ s1 - Norm /@ s2; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.158

```
r3 = Apply[Subtract, Map[Norm] /@ {s1, s2}]; //  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.155

```
Norm /@ {Chop[r1 - r2], Chop[r1 - r3]}
```

> {0, 0}

Did not include `Subtract @@ MapAt[Norm, {s1, s2}, {All, All}]` in timing experiments because computation was aborted due to limitations of the free Wolfram Cloud plan.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You may use the *levelspec* syntax of  [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) with [`Subtract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subtract.html).

[`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) is `Map`ed to the second last level of the list; the vectors. `Subtract` is then [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)ed to the items in the first level of the list.

```
Subtract @@ Map[Norm, {set1, set2}, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {0.000672543,-0.000166313,0.000281282,0.00030175}
> ```

```
Subtract @@ Map[Norm, {set1b, set2b}, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{0.000606338,-0.000177899,0.00024899,-0.0000181312},
>  {-9.51991*10^-6,-0.000710573,-2.60074*10^-8,-3.2146*10^-6}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
Norm /@ set1 - Norm /@ set2
```

If there are extra brackets, then:

```
newset1 = set1[[1]]
```

and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I have added some edit to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Then replace:  `newset1 = set1[[1]]` to eliminate the outer brackets.

Comment: David, it is not extra brackets; `set1b` and `set2b` are 2X4X3 arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
Subtract @@ MapAt[
  Norm
  , {set1, set2}
  , {All, All}
  ]
```

> {0.000672543, -0.000166313, 0.000281282, 0.00030175}

Equivalently

```
Apply[Subtract, Map[Norm] /@ {set1, set2}]
```

Use `Join[set1b, set2b]` instead of `{set1, set2}` for the new case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I have added some edit to the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

If it is about speed, one can do slightly faster (at least on my machine) as follows:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{s1, s2} = RandomReal[1000, {2, 1000000, 3}];

r1 = normDif[s1, s2]; // RepeatedTiming // First

r4 = Subtract[
     Sqrt[(s1^2).ConstantArray[1., 3]],
     Sqrt[(s2^2).ConstantArray[1., 3]]
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First

r1 == r4
```

> 0.0663
>
> 0.024
>
> True

Also quite nice, drawing some more attention to the really useful function `` NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot `` that was shown to me by user21:

```
r5 = Subtract[
     Sqrt[NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[s1, s1]],
     Sqrt[NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[s2, s2]]
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First

r1 == r5
```

> 0.033
>
> True